# How To Send GCM Message More Then 1000 users in one time

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am new to php and GCM. i am using following code to send gcm message using php and mysqldb as i am getting notification successfully however the android guidelines state that gcm message should be send in batch of 1000 each so i am looking for a solution so i can send notification in chunks so all user will receive the notification. i have seen some answers on some similar question but no one seems to be as much detailed for a beginner.

My question is that how i will be able to send GCM message more then 1000 user in one time as i have more then 20,000 users in my scenario. how i will be able to make 1000

Below Is The Code

```
<?php





     include_once 'db_functions.php';




        $db = new DB_Functions();




        $appId= $_POST["appIdSelect"];




if($appId==0)




{




    echo "App not selected, Please choose app first!!";




return;




}




        $users = $db->getAllDevicesByAppId($appId);




        $message = $_POST["message"];




    $message = array("alert" => $message);




    $i=0;




        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {




  $regId = $row["device_id"];




    //$regId."<br/>";




    include_once './GCM.php';





    $gcm = new GCM();





    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);





    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);





    $result;




        $i++;




        }





        echo "Notification send to APP ID= ".$appId." successfully. Total notification sends = ".$i;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1000 limit is for when using the `registration_ids` parameter.

For your scenario, it is suggested to make use of [Topic Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging). Depending on which platform your users are, you simply have to have them subscribe to your topic, and as soon as you send a message to that topic, all subscribers will receive that message.

With all that said, is there a reason why you're not using the newer version of GCM which [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM)?

Comment: Maybe latter in future my client will ask to move on FCM but for now he want it done in GCM..